# Where does my image been stored in Ionic application?

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I am very new to Ionic and Cordova, for the last couple of days I am trying to download an image that I have upload in firebase storage. I want to transfer the image and store it in my mobile device through my mobile application. I have installed all the plugins needed to do that. I have created two buttons. The first button is to display the image in my application and the second button is to download the image in my device. The source code for that is in my storage.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>storage</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
 <button ion-button (click)="display()">Display</button>
 <button ion-button (click)="download()">Download</button>
 <img src="{{imgsource}}">
</ion-content>
```

The functionality is in my storage.ts

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, Platform, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
//import {File,Transfer} from 'ionic-native';
import {FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import {TransferObject} from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import {Transfer} from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';


import firebase from 'firebase';



declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'storage-home',
  templateUrl: 'storage.html',
  providers: [Transfer, TransferObject, File]
})



export class StoragePage {

  storageDirectory: string = '';
  fileTransfer: FileTransferObject;
  nativepath: any;
  firestore = firebase.storage();
  imgsource: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public zone: NgZone) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // make sure this is on a device, not an emulation (e.g. chrome tools device mode)
      if(!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        return false;
      }

      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
      }
      else if(this.platform.is('android')) {
        this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
      }
      else {
        // exit otherwise, but you could add further types here e.g. Windows
        return false;
      }
    });
  }





     display() {
        this.firestore.ref().child('image.jpg').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.imgsource = url;
            this.fileTransfer.download(url,'image.jpg').then((entry) => {
           console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());


           }, (error) => {
          // handle error
           });
           })
        })
      }

     downlad() {
        this.firestore.ref().child('image.jpg').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.imgsource = url;
            this.fileTransfer.download(url,cordova.file.dataDirectory +'image.jpg').then((entry) => {
           console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());


           }, (error) => {
          // handle error
           });
           })
        })
      } 

    }
```

The display button works perfectly as I can see my image when I install the application on my device. The problem though is with the download button as nothing is happening and I don’t know if it’s working as I can’t find my image anywhere in my device. Can anyone please guide me?

Thanks in regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a typo on your download function name.  In the HTML module you refer to download() and in your code your function is labeled as downlad.